# jQuery security and efficiency simple calculation code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//AMOUNT CALCULATOR
            var totalAmount = 0;
            var serviceAmount = 0;

jQuery('.select-service').click(function(){
    var serviceAmount = parseInt(jQuery(this).parent().html().replace(/\D/g,''));
    if(jQuery(this).is('.selected')){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('selected');
        totalAmount -= serviceAmount;
        jQuery('#total-amount').html(totalAmount);
    }else{
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
        totalAmount += serviceAmount;
        jQuery('#total-amount').fadeIn('slow').html(totalAmount);
    }
});
//AMOUNT CALCULATOR
```

is this code efficient and secure? I am PHP dont know if it is required or not to judge.. Please any Help/feed back would be awesome! really trying to better my coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security:**

If you want to check amounts securely, don't do it in the browser alone: you need a server-side validation (e.g. with PHP if it is your language of choice).

**Efficiency:**

1. You can use `$('...')` instead of `jQuery('...')` to improve the readability and concision (source: [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/html/)).
2. Avoid looking for divs with jQuery every time you need them by assigning them to a variable. In this case, caching `$('#total-amount')` seems unnecessary, but it will pay off as soon as you call it once more (see [jQuery Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230727/jquery-optimization-best-practices) for more information).

Thus:

```
//AMOUNT CALCULATOR
var totalAmount = serviceAmount = 0;
// caching $('#total-amount')
var totalAmountDiv = $('#total-amount');

$('.select-service').click(function(){
    // caching $(this)
    var thisDiv = $(this);
    var serviceAmount = parseInt(thisDiv.parent().html().replace(/\D/g,''));
    if(thisDiv.is('.selected')){
        thisDiv.removeClass('selected');
        totalAmount -= serviceAmount;
        totalAmountDiv.html(totalAmount);
    }else{
        thisDiv.addClass('selected');
        totalAmount += serviceAmount;
        totalAmountDiv.fadeIn('slow').html(totalAmount);
    }
});
//AMOUNT CALCULATOR
```

Comment: wow thanks man.. but doesnt using jQuery instead of $ prevent conflicts with mootools?

Comment: Yes it does, I just didn't know you used another library. To avoid conflicts, you can also use `jQuery.noconflict()` or Mootools' Dollar Safe Mode (http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/)